# express session not working

Tags: node.js, session, express

This is my express setup:

```
    server.use(express.cookieParser(config.securitySalt));
    server.use(express.session({
      secret: config.securitySalt,
      cookie: {
        path: '/',
        domain: '.opencubes.io',
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 24
      }
    }));
    server.use(flash());
    require("./passport")(passport, config);
    server.use(passport.initialize());
    server.use(passport.session());
```

However I can't login even on the main domain, unless I remove all the session params. I'm using express 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to be an issue with my browser. t2 connect.sid cookies were set